# Integrate $\int \frac{(1+x^2)dx}{(1−x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $\displaystyle \int \frac{(1+x^2)dx}{(1−x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}$

I don't know how to do this one. I need some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try trig substitution of $x^{2} = \tan(y)$?

Comment: just edited it.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7B%281%2Bx%5E2%29dx%7D%7B%281%E2%88%92x%5E2%29%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bx%5E4%7D%7D; Should that be the answer to my integral? (I don't have the solutions, though)

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the problem correctly?  Your other calculus questions to date have been relatively routine, but this one is not (as your wolframalpha answer indicates).  Life would be a lot easier with an extra $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: @BarryCipra this problem is copied correctly, but what I don't know is what wolframalpha actually calculated ...

Comment: Mathematica gives $$
\sqrt[4]{-1} \left(F\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1}
   x\right)\right|-1\right)-2 \Pi \left(i;\left.\sin ^{-1}\left((-1)^{3/4}
   x\right)\right|-1\right)\right)
$$
where the special functions are the `EllipticF` and `EllipticPi` functions.

Comment: Mathematica does not handle these types of integrals very well, for some reason.  This has been the case since at least version 6.

Comment: @heropup: I have noticed that Mathematica has not handled several of the integrals that I've done for answers recently. However, with most of mine, it has just plain given up, rather than giving an answer that it cannot simplify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These types of integrals are best evaluated using a substitution of the form $$u = x - x^{-1}, \quad du = 1 + x^{-2} \, dx.$$  Note that $u^2 = x^2 + x^{-2} - 2$, and we can write the integrand as $$\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{x^4+1}} dx = \frac{x^2(1+x^{-2}) \, dx}{x^2(x^{-1}-x)\sqrt{x^2+x^{-2}}} = -\frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+2}} = -\frac{u \, du}{u^2 \sqrt{u^2+2}}.$$  Now let $v = \sqrt{u^2+2}$, $dv = \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+2}} \, du$, and the given integral becomes $$\begin{align*} \int \frac{dv}{2-v^2} &= \frac{\log(v+\sqrt{2}) - \log(v-\sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}} + C \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left| \frac{\sqrt{x^2+x^{-2}} + \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+x^{-2}} - \sqrt{2}} \right| + C \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left| \frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}+\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{x^4+1}-\sqrt{2}x} \right| + C. \end{align*}$$

Comment: There seems to be a factor of $-1$ missing, otherwise, this is correct. (+1)

Comment: How do you know what you need to use as $u$? I wouldn't be able to see that myself and it's amazing what you did.

Comment: @L_McClain: usually, it is experience.

Comment: @robjohn: Thought so :)

Comment: It's not a substitution that is commonly taught, as it tends to only apply to integrands of a very specific type.  The only thing I can say is that once you have seen it, you will know.

Comment: That's true. :)

Comment: @heropup: I don't understand how you got this part: $\int \frac{dv}{2-v^2} = \frac{\log(v+\sqrt{2}) - \log(v-\sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}} + C \\ $ Is there a formula to do that or a rule?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{a^2-v^2} = \frac{1}{(a-v)(a+v)} = \frac{1}{2a}\left( \frac{1}{v+a} - \frac{1}{v-a}\right),$$ for $a > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

The integral you  have is equivalent to,
$$
\int \frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2} \frac{\,dx}{x\sqrt{x^2 + x^{-2} -2 + 2}}
$$
Set $u = x - x^{-1}.$ Then the integral reduces to
$$
-\int \frac{\,du}{u\sqrt{u^2 + 2}}.
$$
This looks more promising:
$$
-\int \frac{\,du}{u^2 \sqrt{2u^{-2} + 1}}.
$$
Set $v = u^{-1}.$